# "Application Defined or Object Defined" error in VBA-SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, database-connection

I am trying to write an Exce-Vba code for SQL connection. The code, first will open the connection to the server, then it will copy a 4 columns of table (`Range("C22:G81")`) from my Excel-sheet to the SQL-server (I am only trying to send numerical table now as a test, I don't send any column name)

I have been trying to solve a "Application Defined or Object Defined" error quite long time. I get the error for the connection string `strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;"`

I even tried with another version with password option like `strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; Jet OLEDB:Database Password='passwd';"`

But I get the same error. I am quite new in SQL-coding. I wonder if I am missing something important.

Lasly, I don't know if it is related to this error, but I manually created 4 columns in the SQL server for my 4 columns in the Excel. Do I need to write something specific that those 4 columns in the Excel-sheet will find the right columns in the SQL-server?

Thanks in advance...

The code:

```vb
 Private Sub inlasning()

  Dim MyWorkBook As Workbook
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim ServerName As String, DataBaseName As String, strSQL As String

  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  ServerName = "E45c7642"
  DataBaseName = "Tables"

  ' Specify the OLE DB provider
 conn.Provider = "sqloledb"

 ' Set SQLOLEDB connection properties
 conn.Properties("Data Source").Value = ServerName
 conn.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = DataBaseName

 ' Windows NT authentication.
 conn.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
 conn.Open


  Dim ValidSheet As Worksheet
  Dim HeaderRange As Range
  Dim DataRange As Range
  Dim ColRange As Range
  Dim LastRange As Range
  Dim strName As String, strCon As String

 strName = ThisWorkbook.FullName


   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ValidSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  ' 

    Set HeaderRange = ValidSheet.Range("C20:G21")  
    Set ColRange = HeaderRange.Find(TheHeader, , , xlWhole)
    Set LastRange = ColRange.End(xlDown)
    Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:G81")  ' This is what I am trying to transfer, only numeric values without column names

 strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strName _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;"

 conn.Open strCon

 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & ValidSheet.Name & "$" & Replace(DataRange, "$", "") & "];"
 rs.Open strSQL, dbclass, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

 arrData = rs.GetRows

 rs.Close
 conn.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set conn= Nothing
 Set ValidSheet = Nothing


 End Sub
```

After getting the same error for the "connection string", I changed the strategy, and I used dbclass procedure to open a connection. So the new code is like below. (I found this coding from a guy, but he is on vacation now, so I can't ask him).

It gets connection (dbclass) properties automatically, which are saved in the main ThisWorkbook.  This code doesn't give any error at all, but it doesn't copy the column from the Excel to the database. I tried different versions for the sql-query, like `SQL = .... VALUES('result')` or `SQL = .... VALUES(result)`, but there is no result again, without error.

```
Private Sub Testing_Click()

 Dim FindColValues() As Double
 Dim ValidBook As Workbook
 Dim ValidSheet As Worksheet

 Dim DataRange As Range

 Dim dataa  As Range 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       TheSheet = "Sheet2"
       Set ValidSheet = Worksheets(TheSheet)

       Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C21:C81")

  ' Below creating an array "result(it)" from the seleced range.
   For Each dataa In DataRange
       ReDim Preserve result(it)
       result(it) = dataa.Value
       it = it + 1
   Next

 ' Below is just an alternative array for "in case"  
   arrData = ValidSheet.Range("C22:G81").Value

  SQL = "INSERT INTO Table_test (Column1) VALUES ('result()');"

  dbclass.ExecuteSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Below is dbclass connection properties which is read automatically by the other function:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim connOk As Boolean
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim MyWorkBook As Workbook
   Dim CurSheet As Worksheet

   Set dbclass = New clsDB

   dbclass.Database = "Tables"
   dbclass.ConnectionType = SqlServer
   dbclass.DataSource = "E45c7642"
   dbclass.UserId = Application.UserName

   connOk = dbclass.OpenConnection(False, True)

   If connOk = False Then
   MsgBox "Cannot connect"

   Else
      MsgBox "The server is connected"

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you opening `dbclass` twice? Also, you need to end your connection string with `"...=""Excel 12.0"";"`

Comment: @Bond thanks for the tips. Now I deleted the first connection line `dbclass.Open`, and I added 2 quotation marks at the end as you showed `". . .=""Excel 12.0"";"`. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: OK. Can you edit your question and update it with your new code? I'm also not sure why you're assigning properties to `dbclass` _and_ using a connection string. You would typically use one or the other. They may be causing conflict with one-another. It looks like maybe you're trying to create a SQL and an Excel connection? If so, you'll need two `ADODB.Connection` objects.

Comment: If you're writing this in Excel VBA, I don't think you gain anything by using ADO to get arrData. Just use `arrData = ValidSheet.Range("C22:G81").Value`. That will give you a transposition of what `rs.GetRows` gives you, but you're not doing anything with arrData anyway. Which brings up my next point: I was expecting to see an  INSERT INTO sql statement that puts the data into a table, but I don't see it.

Comment: Thanks Dick and @Bond for the contributions, like I said, i might have done some bbasic mistakes as a newbee.  However, the same error for the connection query remains.

Now I edited my question, I added another coding try with dbclass. It doesn't give error at all, but It doesn't copy the table from the Excel to the server. Can you guys have a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem for my second code. As I wrote before, in my alternative code (second code), I didn't get any error at all in VBA, but it didn't save my table into the server.

Now I know the reason, because my real value was in "comma" format, but the server saved the value in "dot" format. So I added `Str(value)` to convert the "comma" value to the "dot" value, and it works now:

```
....
SQL = "INSERT INTO Table_test (Column1) VALUES (" & Str(result(1)) & ")"
dbclass.ExecuteSQL SQL

End Sub
```